# configuring RoyalSlider JQuery script to work on Shopify

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, shopify

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now so any help is appreciated. I'm also fairly new to this.

I'm trying to install the RoyalSlider JQuery code on Shopify and it doesnt appear to be working. I've converted some of the sample codes to Shopify script but having no luck getting the slider to show up at all.

This is what i'm placing in the header:

```
{{ 'stylesheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'SliderPreview.css.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'royal-slider-1.0.min.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' | script_tag }}
{{ 'jquery-1.5.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'jquery.easing.1.3.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'royal-slider-1.0.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

This is what I have in the body:

```
<script>    
        $(function() {  
            var defaultSlider = new RoyalSlider("#banner-rotator", {
                captionShowEffects:["moveleft", "fade"]             
            });
        });           
    </script>

    {{ page.content }}
    <script>       
    royalSlider.loadTheme('{{ 'royal-slider-1.0.min.js' | asset_url}}');        
        $('#banner-rotator').royalSlider({          
            imageAlignCenter:true,
            hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
            slideshowEnabled: true,
            slideshowDelay:3000,
            slideshowPauseOnHover: true,
            slideshowAutoStart:true,
            slideTransitionSpeed:800,
            slideSpacing:0
        });     
    });
    </script>
```

Then I put this tag on any page where I want the slider to show up:

```
<div id="banner-rotator">
<a href="/"><img src="{{ 'banner.jpg' | asset_url | img_tag }}" alt="{{ bridal `}}"`/></a>`
</div>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

RiyalSlider is up to version 8 now. It may work better for you: http://codecanyon.net/item/royalslider-touchenabled-jquery-image-gallery/461126